# SQL syntax error using Heroku CLI, Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, command-line-interface

I'm using the Heroku CLI to connect to a postgres database of my Heroku webapp and want to insert an intial user into the user table.

When I run `SELECT * FROM user;` i get back my results just fine.

But when I want to INSERT INTO the same table, for example:

`INSERT INTO user (username, email, password_hash, admin, isactive) VALUES ('John Doe', 'john@example.com', 'randompassword','1','1');`

it's throwing errors at me, pointing at the table name:

*ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO User (username, email......*

(with an arrow pointing at the u in user)

I'm super lost...is Heroku using some weird SQL syntax? Does it not support INSERTS?
What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to use `public.user` instead.

(Noticed the table name when doing `\d+ user` was public.user )

As Chris pointed out below - this shouldn't normally be a problem.
For all my other tables I'm quite comfortable querying using just the table - without having to prefix it with `public`.

Having said that, it seems Heroku creates a user table of its own where it stores database users (used for connectivity to the database itself).

So it turns out it's most likely an ambiguity issue as Heroku creates its own `user` table, but my model also has a `user` table.

If I (SELECT) query on just `user` - I get 'Heroku's table.

(and it seems you are unable to INSERT into this table hence the poorly described error)

If I query on `public.user` - I get my own table.

If only the error specified that...  :)

Comment: if this solved your issue, consider marking it as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: This isn't the problem. Yes, out of the box with PostgreSQL things are placed in the `public` schema but the default [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) should make everything work without having to manually specify `public.`.

Comment: Note that the error message shows a capital "U" in "User". I suspect you created the table with a quoted capital letter. Table names should be lowercase in PostgreSQL and you can get weird errors like this if you force it to use capitals.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'll update my answer with my findings and mark it as the answer. (I am unableto mark my own answer to my own question until 48 hours after posting - hence the delay).